# Difference between installing CUDA using nvidia-cuda-toolkit and the .run file

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, cuda

My laptop has a Ubuntu 13.10 installed and has a Nvidia 630M graphics card. I have been trying to install CUDA. I installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

What I want to know is what is the difference between installing it using the above command and the procedure given at the NVIDIA page [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

Comment: does this command work for you? i'm getting dependency error when running this.

Comment: yes, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the version - Ubuntu's repository is a bit behind, as it prefers stability over cutting edge.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to install from 'apt-get'. Because .run file is intended to be an installer for all linux distributions, not only Ubuntu. The 'apt-get' version has been optimized so that it is compatible with Ubuntu distribution. The package may be, as explicitly stated by **VincentSC**, unstable and buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is a bit old now, but wanted to share my recent experience with Ubuntu 12.04 since it's relevant.

Using the package manager (i.e. running the commands listed in the OP), you are required to install package dependencies as usual.  These include the nvidia graphics drivers.  If you have already installed drivers using a .run file downloaded from nvidia, they will be overwritten.

Using the .run file to install cuda, you are given the option to install **only** cuda, leaving your pre-existing drivers intact.

For some reason, on my system the nvidia-331 module listed as a cuda dependency is broken.  Installing it leaves my system unable to boot.  Therefore, the option to install only cuda was very useful, because it meant I could source my own drivers from nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

While this post does answer a question I have, there are quite a few other questions I raised in a separate post that might interest any reader of this question. Here is the link to it: [CUDA sample code did not get installed through sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit; any solutions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812725/cuda-sample-code-did-not-get-installed-through-sudo-apt-get-install-nvidia-cuda).

One big difference I have experienced is that the CUDA sample codes are missing when installing through apt-get; they will be obtained through the .run file (or so it is stated in Nvidia's docs). I hope that someone can answer my question; in my question, I also highlight an apparent difference which is that the location of the CUDA binaries will be different depending on which method you choose, which consequently affect your need of modifying your .bashrc file.

Comment: These should be flagged as duplicates