# which version of CUDA samples on github to choose for nvidia-cuda-toolkit in 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I'm using 20.04 LTS and I installed CUDA from the ubuntu repo using `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. The version displayed by `apt show nvidia-cuda-toolkit` is 10.1.243-3.

However, this package does not come with the samples, [as pointed out in a previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812725/cuda-sample-code-did-not-get-installed-through-sudo-apt-get-install-nvidia-cuda), so I had to look on Nvidia's github for that, [and I found the samples there](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/releases).

However, there's a problem with that page which was neither asked nor answered in the previous question: the releases on that page have versions 10.0, 10.0.1, 10.1, 10.1 update 1, 10.1 update 2, and 10.2. I don't see 10.1.243-3 anywhere there, so it's unclear which of the github releases I should be downloading.

Which one should I download for best compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

For the apt package 10.1.243-3, it seems on the github releases page, that corresponds to **10.1 update 2**.

There are two pieces of evidence that support this:

- right next to 10.1 update 2 on github, there's a "10.1.2". This is the closest to apt package
- on github, under 10.1 update 2, it says "released on Aug 19, 2019". That's the same release date on [the official nvidia doc for cuda 10.1.243](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/).