# "libcuda.so not found" when trying to `make` matrixMulDrv cuda sample after apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I installed cuda using `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` (*not* using the instructions on the Nvidia site). This is known to not install the samples, so I went on github to download them, as explained [in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812725/cuda-sample-code-did-not-get-installed-through-sudo-apt-get-install-nvidia-cuda).

I cd'ed into Samples/deviceQuery and tried `make`, but it complained that nvcc was not found, so I looked at the Makefile and changed the command to `CUDA_PATH=/usr make` and it worked. This works because the Makefile has the definition `CUDA_PATH ?= /usr/local/cuda`, while `apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` actually puts nvcc at `/usr/bin/nvcc`.

Then I tried doing the same thing in Samples/matrixMulDrv, but it gave me a different error:

```
>>> WARNING - libcuda.so not found, CUDA Driver is not installed.  Please re-install the driver. <<<
```

Doing `locate libcuda.so` says I *do* have it, and it's at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

**How can I make matrixMulDrv?**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to compile successfully using the following command:

```
CUDA_PATH=/usr CUDA_SEARCH_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu make
```

Comment: think to run a "ldconfig"